# FOS UserBundle : Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class FormAuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

New to Symfony2, I created a new project using FOS User bundle.

I get this error when I try to log in or register:

URL : http://symfony.local/login_check

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Security\Http\EntryPoint\FormAuthenticationEntryPoint
```

After hours looking around on the web, I am completely lost.

Is there someone to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours to figure it out, I have found that the problem is due to **APC** enabled...

Just turn it off and the problem disappears.

My config :

- Windows 7 (for development)
- Apache 2.4.7
- PHP 5.3.29
- APC version 3.1.?

Answer (score 0):

login_check is not the login page, it is the route which executes the login check script
have you checked your security.yml file to have the proper firewalls and providers etc?
you need to have something like this:

```
security:
 providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
 firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
          pattern: .*
          context: user
          form_login:
              success_handler: authentication_handler
              failure_handler: authentication_handler
              provider:       fos_userbundle
              csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
              login_path:     /user/login
              check_path:     /user/login_check
              default_target_path: /user/dashboard
              always_use_default_target_path: true
          logout:
              path:   /user/logout
              target: /
          anonymous: true
    #fos security configurations
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMINROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/user/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/register, roles: [ ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN ] }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN ] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    acl:
        connection: default
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the /login page. The redirection to /login_check is done by FOS UserBundle. Root and security are both corrects. Do you have another idea?

Comment: When I had problems with FOS it was because of the AppKernel, cache, security.yml, services.yml, config.yml, wrongly imported resources for admin, wrong orm, dbal settings, orm mappings, entity managers